# Rays in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are closed

Tags: general-topology, geometry

A *ray* in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a subset of the form $\{ x + t(y - x) \mid t \geq 0 \}$ for some distinct $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Bourbaki's "General Topology" claim that such a ray is closed, but provide no proof.

I can't find a proof myself. Let $R_{x,y} = \{ x + t(y - x) \mid t \geq 0 \}$. To prove that $R_{x,y}$ is closed, we need to prove that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus R_{x,y}$ open, that is, that for every $z \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus R_{x,y}$ there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(z,\epsilon) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\setminus R_{x,y}$.

$\mathbb{R}^n\setminus R_{x,y}$ seems to consist of points of the form $x + t(y - x)$ where $t < 0$ and those who can't be written in the form $x + t(y - x)$ at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove directly that $R_{x,y}$ is closed by showing that the limit of all converging sequence $\{x_n\in R_{x,y}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is in $R_{x,y}$ itself.

Now here's the proof. If $\{x_n\in R_{x,y}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a converging sequence, there exists $\{t_n\geq0\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\{x + t_n(y-x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a converging sequence, which implies that $\{t_n\geq0\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a converging sequence. Since $\newcommand{\reals}{{\mathbf R}}\{t\in\reals\|t\geq0\}$ is closed, $\lim_{n\to \infty} t_n \geq0$. Thus
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (x + t_n(y-x))
= x + \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n\right)(y-x) \in R_{x,y},
\end{equation}
hence $R_{x,y}$ is closed!

Answer (score 2):

For any fixed vectors $x,z \neq 0$ we have that $L(x,z):=\{x + tz: t \in \Bbb R\}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ via the map $h:t \to x + tz$. It's clearly a bijection and continuous as vector operations are continuous. $L(x,z)$ is itself closed in $\Bbb R^n$ too (as all translations are homeomorphisms of $\Bbb R^n$ and linear subspaces are closed etc.).

The ray is just $h[[0,+\infty)]$ which is closed as $h$ is closed onto $L(x,z)$ and the latter set is closed in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: +1 for avoiding sequences

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I bet there are a few theorems one needs to know to understand your arguments. Can you write them, too? For example, why homeomorphisms (or translation) preserves closedness (if this statement makes sense).

Comment: @SungheeYun homeomorphisms preserve closedness is trivial. That all translations are homeomorphisms is also trivial. Bourbaki does mention these facts.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thx! I think I need to get some basic knowledge about those. Thx for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as Sunghee Yun's answer.

Let $z_n \in S $ (ray) $\rightarrow z$   be a convergent sequence.

Need to show that  $z \in S$.

$z_n=x+t_n(y-x)$ , $x,y \in \mathbb{R^n}$ fixed, $t_n \ge 0$.

Since $z_n$ is Cauchy:

$\epsilon >0$ given; There is a $n_0$ s.t. for

$m \ge n \ge n_0$

$||z_m-z_n||=||(t_m-t_n)(x-y)|| =$

$|t_m-t_n|$ $ ||(x-y)|| < \epsilon$.

$||(x-y)|| =c >0$ ( assuming $x\not =y$, else no ray).

This implies  the sequence  $t_n \ge 0$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R_0^+}$, and has a limit $t\ge 0$.

Hence

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}z_n= z$, with

$z=(x +t(y-x)) \in S$.

Remark:

$||z-z_n|| =|t-t_n|c \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: It'd be better if you could modify your answer mathematically more rigorous.

Comment: Sunghee.Suggest.